# How to add number field to varchar field in oracle. varchar field is time in HH:MM:SS format

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 columns

```
Start_Time (VARCHAR)           Duration_in_sec  (NUMBER)
12:03:11                          220
11:05:33                          345
```

I want to add col2 to col1 to get end time.
How do I do that I tried

```
Select TO_NUMBER(col1)+col2 as end_time from ABC.
```

This is giving me error. Can someone help me with right way.
This is the error I am getting which is straight forward but How to get the right number. I need to do some maniculation on col1 but I am not getting how to do that

```
ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.
```

Comment: ...Actually, I'd be more worried about wondering if you should have a `Start_Date` column, since adding a duration to a time might make it loop days...

Comment: I do have start date column as well .

Comment: Then you might see about getting those two combined into a proper `DateTime` column, which would make the problem much easier to start from (and avoid a host of update/query issues).

Comment: Well this is how it is given to me. I will try to impliment your solution as well. So you are saying combine start date and start time column?

Comment: Yeah.  There's not usually a good reason to have separate date/time columns in preference for a combined value (Oracle actually pushes you in this direction anyways, given they don't have separate types in the first place).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Oracle does not have a `DATETIME` data type - it has `DATE` and `TIMESTAMP` both of which have a time component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way, using the `numToDSInterval` function:

```
select 
   to_date(start_time,'HH24:MI:SS')+numToDSInterval(Duration_in_sec, 'second') 
   from time_seconds;
```

(Uses a table named "time_seconds")

To return just the time string:

```
select 
   to_char(
     to_date(start_time,'HH24:MI:SS')+numToDSInterval(Duration_in_sec, 'second'), 'HH24:MI:SS'
   )
   from time_seconds;
```

So first, it converts the timestamp from a VARCHAR to a DATE, then it increments that DATE by your number of seconds using `numToDSInterval`.

I would add, though, that storing a time as a string seems like a bad idea.  And are your times storied in 24-hour format?  Or 12-hour with AM/PM?  How can you be sure that your strings are parseable into Dates?
  Etc.?  You should be using the right datatypes for the right job.

Comment: I have both the formats 12 hr and 24hr as well. But yeah the columns are varchar. Thats how they designed the table.

Comment: Well, it's poor design, but I guess you sometimes get what you're given.  Either way, my solution should work for the examples you provided.  If so, please consider accepting my solution.

Comment: I think your solution require time in 12hr format. Becoz it is giving me error `hour must be between 1 to 12`. Is there a way to make it work on 24hr format.

Comment: I updated the date parser to use `HH24`.  Should work now.

Comment: After adding it is giving me date not the time. I want to find out the time. Do you have any idea how to do that

Comment: Sure.  Wrap your result in a `to_char`, like this sample: `to_char(result,'HH24:MI:SS')`

Comment: `23:59:59` + `1` will wrap around and give `00:00:00` - you will lose the fact that there is an extra day.

Comment: @MT0, I don't dispute that.  And I think the original asker knows that too, but he/she only wants the time, regardless of the date.  This is also why I emphasized using the right datatype for the right purpose in my answer.

Comment: Yeah I knw this problem . And working on solution for it. For now I wanted time hence didnt pay attention to date. But for long time solution I am working on it

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the start time and duration both to intervals and then add the two intervals. That way you can handle when the duration is more than one day:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/23e4a/3)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( Start_Time, Duration_in_sec ) AS
SELECT '12:03:11', 220 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '11:05:33', 345 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '23:59:59',   1 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT t.*,
       (   TO_TIMESTAMP( start_time, 'HH24:MI:SS' )
         - TO_TIMESTAMP( '00:00:00', 'HH24:MI:SS' )
       ) + NUMTODSINTERVAL( Duration_in_sec, 'SECOND' ) AS end_time
FROM   table_name t
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/23e4a/3/0)**:

```
| START_TIME | DURATION_IN_SEC |     END_TIME |
|------------|-----------------|--------------|
|   12:03:11 |             220 |  0 12:6:51.0 |
|   11:05:33 |             345 | 0 11:11:18.0 |
|   23:59:59 |               1 |    1 0:0:0.0 |
```

A better solution would be to store both the start time and duration as intervals; then you can just add the values:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2de5a0/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  start_time      INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND,
  duration_in_sec INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND
);

INSERT INTO table_name
SELECT INTERVAL '12:03:11' HOUR TO SECOND, INTERVAL '220' SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT INTERVAL '11:05:33' HOUR TO SECOND, INTERVAL '345' SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT INTERVAL '23:59:59' HOUR TO SECOND, INTERVAL '1' SECOND FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT t.*,
       start_time + Duration_in_sec AS end_time
FROM   table_name t
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2de5a0/1/0)**:

```
|   START_TIME | DURATION_IN_SEC |     END_TIME |
|--------------|-----------------|--------------|
|  0 12:3:11.0 |      0 0:3:40.0 |  0 12:6:51.0 |
|  0 11:5:33.0 |      0 0:5:45.0 | 0 11:11:18.0 |
| 0 23:59:59.0 |       0 0:0:1.0 |    1 0:0:0.0 |
```

Comment: Convert the start time and `00:00:00` to timestamps then subtracting two timestamps gives the difference as an interval and then adding two intervals will give the total as another interval.